# No encuentra el audio dentro de src

Tags: java

Tengo una carpeta "audios" dentro de "src", para cuando construya el proyecto pueda reproducir los audios.
Intento abrir el audio pero me salta  "java.lang.NullPointerException"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public void playFalloVibrador1Reponer() {
    try {
        InputStream path;
        path = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audios/vibradores/reponer/1.wav");
        s1v1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
        s2v1.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path));

        s1v1.start();
        sleepThread();//espera 3 segundos para pode reproducir el audio
        s1v1.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(" " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Intenta imprimir la ruta que te está creando para comprobar si está correcta.

Comment: "file:/C:/Users/Roberto%203cs/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Info_Maquinas/build/classes/audios/vibradores/reponer/1.wav " Me imprime otra ruta

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la ruta en la que tienes los audios?

Comment: Me refiero cual es la ruta que sale cortada en tu pregunta.

Comment: s2v1.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path)); aquí tenia el error, por culpa de copiar y pegar, de todas formas me funciona , pero cuando genero el .jar y lo abro, no me reproduce el audio. C:\Users\Roberto 3cs\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Info_Maquinas\src\audios\vibr‌​adores\reponer –

Answer (score 0):

Una buena forma de comprobar si la ruta está bien es lo que te han escrito en los comentarios, a parte de eso, deberías eliminar el `getClass()` como indican en la [siguiente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570523/getresourceasstream-returns-null) de SO en inglés.

Comment: "file:/C:/Users/Roberto%203cs/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Info_Maquinas/build/classes/audios/vibradores/reponer/1.wav"  Me imprime otra ruta

Comment: s2v1.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(path)); aquí tenia el error, por culpa de copiar y pegar, de todas formas me funciona , pero cuando genero el .jar y lo abro, no me reproduce el audio. C:\Users\Roberto 3cs\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Info_Maquinas\src\audios\vibr‌​adores\reponer –

Comment: El audio está ¿dentro o fuera del jar? imagino que la ruta que estás poniendo es absoluta

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que cuando generas los compilados de tu aplicación Java, no se están incluyendo tus archivos de audio. Para facilitar esto, la carpeta donde tengas tus recursos (archivos de audio y demás) debe ser configurada como carpeta de fuentes del proyecto. Una vez puesto eso, podrás acceder a estos archivos con el código que muestras en tu pregunta.

Si usas maven, esto es más sencillo puesto que existe una carpeta src/main/resources. Dentro de esa carpeta, se pueden colocar todos los archivos que no son clases Java, que son recursos de la aplicación, como tus archivos de audio, de configuración, entre otros.

Comment: Vale aclarar que segunda opción, también funcionara con Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Es simple tienes que poner un tag de resources en tu aplicacion maven para que cuando genere la aplicacion incluya estos audios al jar, war o lo que sea que estes haciendo

```
<build> 
 <resources> 
  <resource> 
   <directory>src/main/java</directory> 
   <includes> 
    <include>**/*.xml</include> </includes> 
  </resource> 
 </resources>
 ....
```

Comment: Quiza una respuesta mas detallada sera mejor valorada por la comunidad

Comment: <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

Comment: `  <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>`

Comment: no puedo agregar un codigo bien pero eso el trozo que se agrega

Comment: Hola @programmercito, en este caso este codigo lo debemos incluir en la respuesta principal, como ves los comentarios tienen un tamaño reducido (esto para mejorar la visibilidad de las respuesta. En este momento hice la edición en la respuesta para incluir el codigo :) Esto se hace con la opción | editar | debajo de su respuesta (o pregunta)

Comment: lo tomo en cuentra gracias :)

Comment: perfecto :) gracias por ayudar a la comunidad